# How to write a function to count the number of elements in a list using a Map?

Tags: ocaml

```
module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)

let rec count_with_map (il: int list) =
  match il with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail ->
    match count_with_map tail with
    | (c, n) :: tail when head = n -> (head, n + 1) :: tail
    | tail -> (head, 1) :: tail ;;
```

I think this is right but I kept getting this error.

```
Error: This expression has type (int * int) list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a Count_with_map.IntMap.t
```

Comment: Small note: `module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)` can be more succinctly written: `module IntMap = Map.Make (Int)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a function to count the number of elements in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910376/how-to-write-a-function-to-count-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: @glennsl the use of a map suggests they're tallying up the number of occurrences of each distinct value in a list rather than just counting the total number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your error, it seems `count_with_map` is meant to return an `int IntMap.t` value rather than a list. Your function, though, returns a list instead. It appears you're trying to return an association list. *This approach can work but is inefficient due to the O(n) nature of lookups and updates in association lists. Maps on the other hand have O(log n) lookup and update due to being implemented as balanced binary trees.*

Let's look at the base case for your recursion: an empty list. This maps neatly to an empty *map*, which is very straightforward to express.

```
let rec count_with_map = function
  | [] -> IntMap.empty
```

Now, if the list isn't empty, we can echo your approach of running the operation on the tail of the list. This will return a map.

```
let rec count_with_map = function
  | [] -> IntMap.empty
  | h::t ->
    let map = count_with_map t in
    ...
```

Now, we can't pattern match on an `int IntMap.t` value because the type is abstract, but we can use [`IntMap.update`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.S.html#VALupdate) to either update or insert into that map. Maps are immutable data structures, so we're creating a *new* map.

```
let rec count_with_map = function
  | [] -> IntMap.empty
  | h::t ->
    let init_or_update = function
      | None -> Some 1
      | Some n -> Some (n + 1)
    in
    let map = count_with_map t in
    let map' = IntMap.update h init_or_update map in
    map'
```

### Alternatively...

Tallying the unique elements in a list is *much* simpler if the list is *sorted*. Then we're merely implementing a [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

```
# let[@tail_mod_cons] rec rle ?(acc=[]) lst =
    match lst, acc with
    | [], _ -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs, (y, z)::ys when x = y -> rle ~acc: ((y, z+1)::ys) xs
    | x::xs, _ -> rle ~acc: ((x, 1)::acc) xs;;
val rle : ?acc:('a * int) list -> 'a list -> ('a * int) list = <fun>
```

And tallying is just applying this to a sorted list.

```
# let tally lst =
    lst 
    |> List.sort compare 
    |> rle;;
val tally : 'a list -> ('a * int) list = <fun>
# tally [1; 3; 5; 7; 7; 8; 10];;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (3, 1); (5, 1); (7, 2); (8, 1); (10, 1)]
```

Then to get a map from this you just need to use `IntMap.of_list`.

Comment: It gives me error like this
Error: Unbound value IntMap.update

Comment: Have you perhaps removed the `module IntMap ...` line from the top of the code?

Comment: I did not include the module definition, no.